# cannot login with basic java web

Tags: java

I'm beginner in java and I am practicing basic java web. In this ex, I cannot login with another username, only "admin"'s username is accept. Where is error??

```
//admin.jsp 
<%
MemberDAO member = new MemberDAO();
%>
<h1>Welcome ${member.getUsername()} to the system</h1>
<a href="ControllerServlet?action=logout">Log out</a>


//login.jsp
<form action="ControllerServlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="login" name="action"/>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>

// ControllerServlet.java
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
    if (action == null || action.equals("logout")){
        dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
    }
    else if(action.equals("login")){

        MemberDAO dao = new MemberDAO();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        if(dao.checklogin(username)){
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("admin.jsp");
        }
        else{
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
        }
    }
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

// MemberDAO.java
public boolean checklogin(String username){
    if (username != null && username.equals("admin"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And I have Member.java, it has contructor and username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually *look at your code*?:

```
public boolean checklogin(String username){
    if (username != null && username.equals("admin"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

What do you *expect* this method to do?  You've hard-coded logic that the username *must* be `"admin"` and nothing else.  So the only valid username is `"admin"` in this case.

If you want the code to behave differently, you'll have to change it in some way.